# How to get iframe content or link in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, puppeteer

First of all, I am sorry for my English. I am not a native speaker, so. I am working on a news application on React Native. I am doing a news-scraper on puppeteer for that. The trouble is in an iframe. I can't get it. I tried to evaluate the page and used querySelector. It doesn't find it.
What should I do? I just want to get the iframe content or link to display it in .

The page that I want to scrape - [link](https://sharij.net/lukashenko-my-ne-mozhem-stat-ukrainoj-i-voevat-protiv-rossii)

There, I need to take a telegram iframe. I've successfully made scraping its header, content, article photo, etc. So, I only need the code for iframe scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
    await page.goto(`https://sharij.net/lukashenko-my-ne-mozhem-stat-ukrainoj-i-voevat-protiv-rossii`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 })
    await page.waitForSelector("iframe[id^=telegram]")
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const frameDocument = document.querySelector("iframe[id^=telegram]").contentWindow.document  // this is the solution
        const videoMessage = frameDocument.querySelector("div.tgme_widget_message") // just for checking that we can access elements
        console.log(videoMessage.innerText)

        // in same way you can get anything now from this iframe :)
    })
```

Comment: On call `.contentWindow.document` it returns: VM1810:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:90